# Latex \layout dotted lines meaning

Tags: geometry, layout, dimensions

I'm using the `geometry` and `layout` packages to set and preview my final layout in my latex document.
[image]

What are the dotted lines (1 and 2) representing and how do you move them?

If I set the `hmargin` and `vmargin` to 0.

```tex
 \geometry{
 paper=letterpaper,
 hmargin=0pt,
 vmargin=0pt
 }
```

The margins are gone but those dotted lines are still there.
[image]

Here is my MWE

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}

 \geometry{
 paper=letterpaper,
 hmargin=0pt,
 vmargin=0pt
 }
 
\begin{document}

\section{}
\layout
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX.SE! Could you provide a MWE please? See for that https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: As explained in the figure: The vertical dashed line is 1in + `\hoffset` and the horizontal dashed line is 1in + `\voffset`. Usually you don't need to change them. `\hoffset` and `\voffset` are usually needed to arrange a page of a given size to a printing paper of a different (larger) size. For example using package `crop` usually would use them. Maybe see also the difference of `paper` and `layout` in the `geometry` manual.

Comment: It should be described in said packages manual; did you read it? Or have a looke here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout . You probably use the wrong variables.